# UK resident freelancing for EU clients -- do I need to send a certificate of UK residence every time I invoice a client?

Tags: uk, eu

I'm a UK freelancer doing various design projects for some EU clients (Italy/France). I'm registered as a sole-trader in the UK and I've just sent my first invoice to a client. The client has asked for a certificate of my UK residence so that their government understands that I will be paying tax in the UK (this is what they've told me).

Is there an easier way of doing this? The process for getting a certificate of residence is around 15 days, and if I have to apply for one each month I send an invoice then it becomes a problem.

Should I include my UTR number on the invoice? What can I do?

Comment: Should I include my UTR number on the invoice? *NO!!!* A thousand times *NO!!!* It's not like a NINO, where an employer needs it. Your UTR is solely **your** reference. VAT number would do the trick (they start with GB)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a EU-VAT number. This number should be on any invoice. Your clients can check its validity Here:
http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/

IF you do not have such a number, get one from you financial authorities.